# ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification --- Error occered

Tags: oracle, plsql

My trigger is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger TA_C_WARRANTY_AUDIT_TRG
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON TA_WARRANTY
FOR EACH ROW`enter code here`
ENABLE
DECLARE
  v_user VARCHAR2(30);
  v_date VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
SELECT user, TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO v_user,v_date FROM dual;
IF INSERTING THEN
  INSERT INTO TA_C_WARRANTY_AUDIT(new_name,old_name,user_name,entry_date,operation)
  VALUES (:NEW.LAST_UPDATE_ID, NULL,v_user,v_date,'Insert');
ELSIF DELETING THEN  
  INSERT INTO TA_C_WARRANTY_AUDIT(new_name,old_name,user_name,entry_date,operation)
  VALUES (NULL, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_ID,v_user,v_date,'Delete');
ELSIF UPDATING THEN  
  INSERT INTO TA_C_WARRANTY_AUDIT(new_name,old_name,user_name,entry_date,operation)
  VALUES (:NEW.LAST_UPDATE_ID, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_ID,v_user,v_date,'Update');
END IF;
END;
/
```

Looks my code is okay but I got below error message:
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Any suggession or idea will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
CREATE TABLE TA_C_WARRANTY_AUDIT
(
    new_name                                VARCHAR2(30),
    OLD_name                                VARCHAR2(30),
    user_name                               VARCHAR2(30),
    entry_date                              VARCHAR2(30),
    operation                               VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Comment: ``enter code here`` ?

Comment: Is `TA_C_WARRANTY_AUDIT.ENTRY_DATE` really a varchar2 column? Seems like a DATE would make more sense. And why select from dual?

Comment: Please post the DDL statements of your tables, so that we can try to compile the trigger.

Comment: Yes it is VARCHAR2 column. To get the logged name and date ... that's why I have used dual

Comment: CREATE TABLE TA_C_WARRANTY_AUDIT(
  new_name VARCHAR2(30),
  OLD_name VARCHAR2(30),
  user_name VARCHAR2(30),
  entry_date VARCHAR2(30),
  operation VARCHAR2(30)
);

Comment: Please, both tables, and editing the question, not adding comments, so that in the end the question can be complete.

Comment: I am sorry Aleksej.

Comment: What Oracle's version do hoy have? because 'enable' is not valir for prior to Oracle 11g

Comment: Luis Caig - I am using Oracle 10.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to remove ENABLE from your code

Comment: Thanks. Let me try!

Comment: Aleksej, 'enter code here' is mistakenly put there. Please overlook that. If ENABLE is okay(!) ... Then it is throwing the exception.